# suggestions with non REST HTTP interface proposal

Tags: rest

I hope this question will be accepted by stack overflow and not be tagged "opinion based". At least I try...

I talked with a supplier that have to develop for us a web application and The agreement was to use a RESTful interface to access to  services provided by my infrastructure.

The REST interface will be developed by my team and their team will develop the UI Interface. The API is in an advanced state of development and it is used by the main application my company is using, so I have to extend it to accomodate this new webapp.

He sent me a draft document to interface their client applications telling me to develop services like this:

http://1.2.3.4:8080/getGPSPositions

telling me:

1) the web frontend will use POST to ask its requests on the above URL
2) the frontend will send objects serialized using JSON with a format  s like this (simplified)

```
{ 
     serviceID: <number>
     fromDate: <date>
     toDate: <date>
     customSQLWhere: <string>
     customSQLOrderBy: <string>
}
```

and response like this:

```
{
    gps_points:
    { 
        #some data object
    }
}
```

This is no REST to me, but JSON+HTTP+RPC with some embedded SQL code, that can be used by an attacker to do some SQL injection...

I think that the correct resource for the above example (about gpsPositions) is:

http://1.2.3.4:8080/gPSPositions?fromDate=...&toDate=...

using HTTP/GET and not HTTP/POST (using fro CRUD operations GET,DELETE,PUT and POST).

I would like to know the technical implications that this kind of approach can have on my project. the API will be exposed on the Internet and in the future it should be used by more supplier for different kind of applications. I also fear to develop an API with two different styles (RPC and REST) should be difficult to read and understand and this will be a problem in the future.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: You're right, it is something that have to be addressed by the business. I wanted to know some thoughts aboute the implications on the project(s) using the (in my opionin) wrong decision on going on with this kind RPC/HTTP...

Comment: if you have hired the supplier, and you're paying to them to develop something for you, then you have the leverage to dictate the contract. That being said, I've seen many cases where POST is used for reads on resources, when the param list is very long or was a "security" requirement by the client (e.g. you don't expose stuff in the URL etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, neither the OP nor his supplier have a correct understanding of REST, IMO.

REST is an architectural style which basically describes how client and servers should interact with each others in order to decouple the former from the latter. The decoupling is achieved by using a backing protocol (HTTP in your case) as transport layer and utilizing the available operations to exchange data. HTTP, which at its core is actually just a protocol to manage resources on a remote location, therefore defines the semantics of each operation, not REST. The decoupling is furthermore achieved by adhering to the rules outlined by the backing transport protocol and by generating new (or utilizing existing) media types both parties can use. Instead of clients coupling to the server API, both couple to intermediary media types instead. This is why Fielding stressed that REST APIs [`should spend almost all of their descriptive efforts in defining the media types used for representing resources`](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).

Media types per se are just textual descriptions of the syntax and the semantic to expect on receiving data annotated to be of that kind. It is thus a knowledge base for peers on how to process the data and give the data some useful meaning. Clients and servers should further use content negotiation to agree on a common media type both understand. I.e. a client could send a server a list of media types the client knows of and the server will pick the one that is probably most suitable of for the available data or send an unsupported media type failure back to the client to indicate that none of the requested media types is known by the server.

It is furthermore important that the server provides clients with all of the information the client could need to take further actions. The client shouldn't parse meaning out of provided URIs but use the relation name instead and look up the semantics of the relation name within the exchanged media type, i.e. or rely on common standards like `next`, `prev`, `first`, `last` and `self` in a collection. This gives the server the freedom to change URIs (and thus move resources around freely) without breaking clients.

One common error of so called RESTful APIs (and clients using those) is, that data is exchanged as `application/json` or `application/hal+json` or the like media type only and clients expect resources to be of a certain type ([typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html)), which already couple clients to the API. First, `application/json` or `application/xml` is a bad media-type in general as it does not hint the users on what content the document might contain. As the example code contains geo-location data probably [`application/vnd.geo+json`](https://sgillies.net/2014/05/22/the-geojson-media-type.html) would be more appropriate in that particular case.

As REST's focus is on resources, it is questionable IMO if geo-location data make up for a good resource. I at least consider them more of some kind of property of an entity that I'd express as resource. As the location seems to change over time this might be some kind of vehicle information (car, bus, truck, plane, ship, ...) or the like. The proposed response is in itself not very self-descriptive. The client therefore has to have some build in knowledge that somethin like `gps_points` in a JSON payload contain GPS data probably as time series for someting.

If the server decicdes to return data in a slightly different representation the client risks to break easily this way. On relying on common media types this risk is almost erased unless both parties adhere to the media types specification.

---

As your actual post more or less questions if `POST` requests are feasible instead of `GET` request on retrieving data:

Accoroding to [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.1) the client expresses his intent by using one of the available operations defined within the spec. `POST` is actually an optional operation that should be used if none of the other operations fits the needs. It is kind of a swiss-army knife that can be misued easily. Using it for other operations is not wrong per se. The spec here states:

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics.

On retrieving data, `GET` is the preferable operation in case the request does not modify any state on the server or requires to extensive data in via a body (as plenty of HTTP clients limit the length of URIs that can be invoked).

The actual implication of accepting data retrieval via POST is, that this becomes part of your API and you have to support it further on. If you decide to later on "fix" this issue you risk of breaking clients that used this kind of communicating with your API. Some legacy systems might force you though to use such constructs. We have some RPC like Web services where we have to provide services to a wide variety of clients. Some of these are SOAP clients in an old SAP version that gets misued in order to send data to our services. As there is actually no build-in support for HTTP in that ABAP version (as far as I'm told) we have to accept such retrieval requests per POST as well. As I changed our API once in order to accept only GET data retrieval I broke plenty of legacy clients that way unintentionally (even once that could retrieve via GET actually) as the developers just used the first sample in the documentation, which was still POST at that time. Long story short, I had to roll back the changes and support both kinds of queries from now on.